# How to save specific values from JSON data with Python

Tags: python, json

I need to save specific values from a complex JSON object

```
json = [
  {
    "InvoiceNumberPrefix": "WH-",
    "InvoiceNumber": 44444,
    "OrderID": 9405944401,
    "CustomerID": 3233,
    "OrderDate": "2020-07-17T12:58:43",
    "OrderStatusID": 1,
    "LastUpdate": "2020-07-17T13:58:43",
    "UserID": "",
    "SalesPerson": "Dava",
    "ContinueURL": "http://",
    "AlternateOrderID": "",
    "OrderType": "Repeat",
    "PaymentTokenID": 0,
    "BillingFirstName": "John",
    "BillingLastName": "Doe",
    "BillingCompany": "3dcart",
    "BillingAddress": "1234 Test St.",
    "BillingAddress2": "",
    "BillingCity": "Tamarac",
    "BillingState": "FL",
    "BillingZipCode": "33321",
    "BillingCountry": "US",
    "BillingPhoneNumber": "7779998822",
    "BillingEmail": "",
    "BillingPaymentMethod": "3dcart Test Payment",
    "BillingOnLinePayment": false,
    "BillingPaymentMethodID": "177",
    "ShipmentList": [
      {
        "ShipmentID": 0,
        "ShipmentLastUpdate": "2020-07-17T13:58:43",
        "ShipmentBoxes": 1,
        "ShipmentInternalComment": "",
        "ShipmentOrderStatus": 1,
        "ShipmentAddress": "1234 Test St.",
        "ShipmentAddress2": "",
        "ShipmentAlias": "",
        "ShipmentCity": "Tamarac",
        "ShipmentCompany": "3dcart",
        "ShipmentCost": 0,
        "ShipmentCountry": "US",
        "ShipmentEmail": "fff",
        "ShipmentFirstName": "John",
        "ShipmentLastName": "Doe",
        "ShipmentMethodID": 48,
        "ShipmentMethodName": "*Shipping Charges Will Be Added Later*",
        "ShipmentShippedDate": "",
        "ShipmentPhone": "34898394833",
        "ShipmentState": "FL",
        "ShipmentZipCode": "33321",
        "ShipmentTax": 0,
        "ShipmentWeight": 2.85,
        "ShipmentTrackingCode": "",
        "ShipmentUserID": "",
        "ShipmentNumber": 1,
        "ShipmentAddressTypeID": 0
      }
    ],
    "OrderItemList": [
      {
        "CatalogID": 2222,
        "ItemIndexID": 33333,
        "ItemID": "44444",
        "ItemShipmentID": 0,
        "ItemQuantity": 10,
        "ItemWarehouseID": 0,
        "ItemDescription": "Widget",
        "ItemUnitPrice": 0,
        "ItemWeight": 0.27,
        "ItemOptionPrice": 12.5,
        "ItemAdditionalField1": "",
        "ItemAdditionalField2": "",
        "ItemAdditionalField3": "",
        "ItemPageAdded": "admin/phone_order.asp",
        "ItemAvailability": "",
        "ItemDateAdded": "2020-07-17T12:57:41",
        "ItemUnitCost": 10,
        "ItemUnitStock": 4444444,
        "ItemOptions": "",
        "ItemCatalogIDOptions": "",
        "ItemSerial": "",
        "ItemImage1": "",
        "ItemImage2": "",
        "ItemImage3": "",
        "ItemImage4": "",
        "ItemWarehouseLocation": "",
        "ItemWarehouseBin": "",
        "ItemWarehouseAisle": "",
        "ItemWarehouseCustom": "",
        "RecurringOrderFrequency": 0
      },
      {
        "CatalogID": 888,
        "ItemIndexID": 000000090,
        "ItemID": "33333333",
        "ItemShipmentID": 0,
        "ItemQuantity": 1,
        "ItemWarehouseID": 0,
        "ItemDescription": "Widget2",
        "ItemUnitPrice": 10,
        "ItemWeight": 0.15,
        "ItemOptionPrice": 0,
        "ItemAdditionalField1": "",
        "ItemAdditionalField2": "",
        "ItemAdditionalField3": "",
        "ItemPageAdded": "admin/phone_order.asp",
        "ItemAvailability": "",
        "ItemDateAdded": "2020-07-17T13:58:13",
        "ItemUnitCost": 5.74,
        "ItemUnitStock": 99983059,
        "ItemOptions": "",
        "ItemCatalogIDOptions": "",
        "ItemSerial": "",
        "ItemImage1": "",
        "ItemImage2": "",
        "ItemImage3": "",
        "ItemImage4": "",
        "ItemWarehouseLocation": "",
        "ItemWarehouseBin": "",
        "ItemWarehouseAisle": "",
        "ItemWarehouseCustom": "Singles / Units",
        "RecurringOrderFrequency": 0
      }
    ],
    "PromotionList": [],
    "OrderDiscount": 0,
    "OrderDiscountCoupon": 0,
    "OrderDiscountPromotion": 0,
    "SalesTax": 0,
    "SalesTax2": 0,
    "SalesTax3": 0,
    "OrderAmount": 135,
    "AffiliateCommission": 0,
    "TransactionList": [],
    "CardType": "",
    "CardNumber": "",
    "CardName": "John Doe",
    "CardExpirationMonth": "",
    "CardExpirationYear": "",
    "CardIssueNumber": "",
    "CardStartMonth": "",
    "CardStartYear": "",
    "CardAddress": "",
    "CardVerification": "",
    "OfflinePaymentFieldList": [],
    "RewardPoints": "",
    "QuestionList": [
      {
        "QuestionAnswerIndexID": 527093,
        "OrderID": 44444423,
        "QuestionID": 1,
        "QuestionTitle": "<b>Before placing your order, please read & agree to our <a href=\"www.partynuts.com/Online-Policy_ep_41-1.html\" target=\"_blank\"> Online Policy</a>.</b>",
        "QuestionAnswer": "",
        "QuestionType": "Checkbox",
        "QuestionCheckoutStep": 2,
        "QuestionSorting": 1,
        "QuestionDiscountGroup": 0
      },
      {
        "QuestionAnswerIndexID": 527094,
        "OrderID": 905901,
        "QuestionID": 2,
        "QuestionTitle": "<b>Before placing your order, please read & agree to our <a href=\"www.partynuts.com/Shipping-Policy_ep_2-1.html\" target=\"_blank\"> Shipping Policy</a>.</b>",
        "QuestionAnswer": "",
        "QuestionType": "Checkbox",
        "QuestionCheckoutStep": 2,
        "QuestionSorting": 2,
        "QuestionDiscountGroup": 0
      },
      {
        "QuestionAnswerIndexID": 527095,
        "OrderID": 905901,
        "QuestionID": 15,
        "QuestionTitle": "Is it ok to ship your order as PARTIAL SHIPMENT*? (split and ship now-OR-wait for completed order) *You will pay for only 1 shipping fee on partial, not 2.",
        "QuestionAnswer": "Skip Question",
        "QuestionType": "Radio",
        "QuestionCheckoutStep": 2,
        "QuestionSorting": 3,
        "QuestionDiscountGroup": 0
      },
      {
        "QuestionAnswerIndexID": 527096,
        "OrderID": 905901,
        "QuestionID": 10,
        "QuestionTitle": "What is your DIRECT or CELL PHONE #? (Failure to put a # may result in delays due to questions right before shipment)",
        "QuestionAnswer": "",
        "QuestionType": "Text",
        "QuestionCheckoutStep": 2,
        "QuestionSorting": 4,
        "QuestionDiscountGroup": 0
      },
      {
        "QuestionAnswerIndexID": 527097,
        "OrderID": 905901,
        "QuestionID": 9,
        "QuestionTitle": "Do you need Saturday Delivery? (make sure to select Sat. Delivery...its an extra fee on top over overnight shipping): ",
        "QuestionAnswer": "No",
        "QuestionType": "Radio",
        "QuestionCheckoutStep": 2,
        "QuestionSorting": 6,
        "QuestionDiscountGroup": 0
      }
    ],
    "Referer": "PHONE ORDER",
    "IP": "50.84.210.66",
    "CustomerComments": "",
    "InternalComments": "",
    "ExternalComments": ""
  }
]
```

I need to save "ItemID" and "ItemQuantity". Before I was able to save this data to variables just by using things like `[0]['OrderItemList'][0]['ItemID']`

However, the JSON data can be dynamic at times there can be 10 or just one "ItemID" and "ItemQuantity".

Is there anything I can do to best save this data?

***UPDATE***

Per some comments, I have tried to do the following

```
for x in json:
  print(x['ItemID'])
```

This returns

```
NameError: name 'false' is not defined
```

Comment: Use a `for` loop to iterate over all the items.

Comment: Instead of hard-coding index `0`.

Comment: What's the question here? Why don't you simply iterate over the array and pull out the members you need from each array item?

Comment: Hello, all thank you very much for the comments, I have updated my questions. Please if you can take a look, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json` variable contains a JSON. It is not a python object so that's why you're receiving this error `NameError: name 'false' is not defined`.
Your JSON contains this line `"ItemIndexID": 000000090,` which is not a valid key-value pair this also makes it invalid JSON.

**Solution:**
I've created a file and pasted that JSON content into that file by removing the leading zeros in `"ItemIndexID": 000000090,` to `"ItemIndexID": 90,`.

```
import json

with open("file.json") as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)

for d in data:
    for i in d["OrderItemList"]:
        print(i.get("ItemID"))
        print(i.get("ItemQuantity"))
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! This was driving me crazy. I can't believe it was so simple, thanks again!